# WebClient change body request per time

Tags: java, webclient

I made a post request with body using WebClient:

```
    WebClient client = WebClient.create();
    RequestDTO requestBody = new RequestDTO("getAll", new RequestDataDto(1, 60)); //Have a class for body request ("start": 1, "finish": 60)

    ProductWrapperMars response = client.post()
            .uri(new URI("myURL"))
            .header("sid", "mySid") //I have a header as well
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(requestBody)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Product.class)
            .block();
```

Here is my classes:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class RequestDTO {
    private String command;
    private RequestDataDto data;

}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class RequestDataDto {

    private Integer start;
    private Integer finish;
}
```

I want to change my requestBody so that "start" could change by +10 every time I call my method. How can I solve this?

Comment: Wont a simple loop work?   You will need to make a new POST request everytime with a new RequestDataDto(x+10, 60)

Comment: Can you provide example?

Comment: If you’re calling `block()` just use `RestTemplate`.

Comment: No, I have to make it only with WebClient, cause it has some further work to do